# having issue with updating label asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax, webforms

I am trying a simple ajax form where it will update a label on button click.

I get the below error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message
>   received from the server could not be parsed.

at below function on line : "throw error;"

```
function Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_endPostBack(error, executor, data) {
    if (this._request === executor.get_webRequest()) {
        this._processingRequest = false;
        this._additionalInput = null;
        this._request = null;
    }
    var handler = this._get_eventHandlerList().getHandler("endRequest");
    var errorHandled = false;
    if (handler) {
        var eventArgs = new Sys.WebForms.EndRequestEventArgs(error, data ? data.dataItems : {}, executor);
        handler(this, eventArgs);
        errorHandled = eventArgs.get_errorHandled();
    }
    if (error && !errorHandled) {
        ***throw error;***
    }
}
```

Here is my form code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Hello";
    }
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Test Form
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="text-align: left; height: 395px;">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>                
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
               <br />
               <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" style="margin-left: 66px" Text="Button" Width="176px" />
               <br />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>

</asp:Content>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is not MVC, just plain old .net webforms :)

Comment: It has been awhile since I have used updatePanels, but should your button1 be outside of the update panel in this scenario?  I might be way off base with that though...

Comment: @Tommy Keeping button1 outside of update panel does get rid of the error, However the Lable1 text is still not updated to "Hello"

Answer (score 1):

I inserted the code above into empty aspx page, removed reference to masterpage and asp:Content and it worked for me. The label changed its text.
If it still doesn't work for you you may use Firefox+Firebug to see the actual server response after clicking on a button. It may contain detailed exception that will give you a hint.